# How to make a SQL query to get a result I need?

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, pivot

I need some help to get how to do this (a simplified case):
There are three tables: athletes, referees, and raitings:

```
--
create table t_athletes
(
    id number,
    name varchar(100)
);

--
create table t_referees
(
    id number,
    name varchar(100)
);

--
create table t_rating
(
    athlete_id number,
    referee_id number,
    val number
);

insert into t_athletes values (1, 'Smith');
insert into t_athletes values (2, 'Jones');
insert into t_athletes values (3, 'Davis');

insert into t_referees values (100, 'Ref Scott');
insert into t_referees values (200, 'Ref Tiger');

insert into t_rating values (1, 100, 2);
insert into t_rating values (1, 200, 5);

insert into t_rating values (2, 100, 5);
insert into t_rating values (2, 200, 4);

insert into t_rating values (3, 100, 1);
insert into t_rating values (3, 200, 3);
```

And I need to get a result like this:

```
        | Ref Scott | Ref Tiger
--------+-----------+----------
Smith   |         2 |         5
Jones   |         5 |         4
Davis   |         1 |         3
```

Well and the number of referees and the number of athletes are not given - maybe two or maybe 10

How to do this?

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pivot over a fixed list of referees, you can join and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    ah.name, 
    sum(case when re.name = 'Ref Scott' then ra.val else 0 end) ref_scott,
    sum(case when re.name = 'Ref Tiger' then ra.val else 0 end) ref_tiger
from t_athletes ah
inner join t_rating ra   on ra.athlete_id = ah.id
inner join t_referees re on re.id = ra.referee_id
group by ah.id, ah.name
order by ah.name desc
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=561e7e63a178f022aaded7da37589dd6)**:

```
NAME  | REF_SCOTT | REF_TIGER
:---- | --------: | --------:
Smith |         2 |         5
Jones |         5 |         4
Davis |         1 |         3
```

Comment: And what to do if the list of referees is not fixed as well as the list of athletes?

Comment: Then in that case you need dynamic query in PL/SQL block. Static SQL must have defined number of columns